# Why does `find` take a parameter by reference and then dereference it?

Tags: rust, iterator

In the following snippet, I do not understand why the closure takes its parameter `s` by reference (`&s`), then dereferences it (`*s`):

```
fn main() {
    let needle = "list".to_string();
    let haystack = [
       "some".to_string(), 
        "long".to_string(),
        "list".to_string(),
        "of".to_string(),
        "strings".to_string(),
    ].to_vec();

    if let Some(str) = haystack.iter().find(|&s| *s == needle) {
        println!("{}", needle);
    } else {
        println!("Nothing there...");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It would be nice if you were a little more precise on *what* seems confusing to you. The use of `||`, the absence of `return`, the fact that `needle` is not explicitly captured (so how does it whether to capture by reference or value), ...

Comment: Sorry: What confuses me is the use of |&s| in the closure parameter, and while also needing to use *s inside the closure.

Comment: `find(|&s| s == &needle)` looks fine to me

Comment: Ah interesting I didn't think of that. Thank you. Is &needle what Matthieu meant by capturing by reference?

Comment: I think `if haystack.contains(&needle)` is more idiomatic for `Vec`

Comment: This is **specifically** called out in [the documentation for the method you are using](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find): *Because `find()` takes a reference, and many iterators iterate over references, this leads to a possibly confusing situation where the argument is a double reference. You can see this effect in the examples below, with `&&x`.*

Answer (score 4):

It is idiomatic. Some people might have different preference for what exactly is dereferenced when, and/or use `.as_str()` instead of dereferencing, but in general it's OK.

---

In your case `.iter()` iterates over `String`s by reference, so it gives `&String` elements.

Then `.find()` gives you access to each iterated the element by reference *again*, so you end up with a `&&String` argument. Even though that reference of reference isn't ideal in this particular case, `.find()` is a generic function that has to consistently work with any type, so it just blindly makes a reference.

---

In arguments `&s` is the *opposite* of taking a reference. The closure argument syntax is:

```
|pattern: type|
```

and the type is optional. So what you're left with is the *pattern*.

Your closure is then:

```
|pattern: &&String|
```

and with your pattern:

```
|&s: &&String|
```

matches one level of `&`, so you end up with `s` being `&String`.

And then you want to compare `s` of type `&String` with a `String`. To compare equal types, you dereference `&String` to `String` with `*s`.

Comment: *&s is the opposite of taking argument by reference* — no, it's not. It still takes an argument by reference, it just immediately dereferences it. `foo(bar: &String)` and `foo(bar: String)` are opposites in this dimension.